# WooCommerce woocommerce_rest_authentication_error on WordPress localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to get solution for this issue but can't find it out.

I'm developing a WordPress plugin using Woocommerce APIs, i.e trying to insert a product reading from external JSON source. So when I try to call

```
$woocommerce->get( 'products', $data );
```

I get a fatal error like that:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Firma non valida - la firma fornita non corrisponde. [woocommerce_rest_authentication_error] in /Users/hal/Documents/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/.../vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:324
```

(StackTrace not reported here, not useful to find other informations).

Error reported is **401**, about this most weird thing is that the same code on localhost does not work, if I upload & try same code it on production VPS ... it works. Searched on many topics about this, no clear responses until now so sorry for duplicate, if is this the case.

$woocommerce was previously instanced as:

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
            'http://localhost/wordpress',
            'ck_...', // Your consumer key
            'cs_...', // Your consumer secret
            [
            'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
            'version' => 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
        ]
);
```

ck/cs pairs was just generated from wordpress, site url is obviously http://localhost/wordpress (and I tried without success i.e http://localhost/wordpress**/**, http**s**://localhost/wordpress and so on)

If this could matter (...and I guess yes), I'm trying to debug this code on MAMP (apache on 80 port, mysql on 3306) running @ localhost w/ basic installation, on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Hope I was clear and anyone solved this problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using http request then you have to user oauth for authorization for rest api